# Textures are Black in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a model i'm exporting from blender 2.76b into json and then loading with three.js 71. Blender the model looks fine. In webGL the model is completely black. I'm think it has something to do with the textures but i'm not sure. The model is a fairly complex model made from maya and exported as an fbx. I've tested with simpler models and different textures and not had any problems but there's something wrong with this one.

Any suggestions would be appreciated greatly.

Link to the json: http://we.tl/GnQiOfAhOD

Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>MultiLoader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #000;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                z-index: 10;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: underline;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #stats { position: absolute; top:0; left: 0 }
            #stats #fps { background: transparent !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsText { color: #aaa !important }
            #stats #fps #fpsGraph { display: none }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">MultiLoader Testing</div>




  <script src="build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>

  <script>
    WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

    VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
    ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 10000;

    var container, stats;
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        // SCENE
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 500, 10000 );

        //  CAMERA
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        camera.position.set(60, 40, 120);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        scene.add(camera);


        //LIGHTS

        var front = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 5.4 );
        front.position.set( 0, 140, 1500 );
        front.position.multiplyScalar( 1.1 );
        //front.color.setHSL( 0.6, 0.075, 1 );
        scene.add( front );

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);     
        scene.add( ambient );

        var back = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
        back.position.set( 0, -140, -1500); 
        scene.add( back );


        //Avatar Tests



        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('models/Maya/modelExport.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
            material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
            avatar = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            }
        );
        loader.onLoadComplete=function(){
            avatar.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
            var position = new THREE.Vector3(0,-20,0);
                avatar.position.add(position);
            scene.add( avatar );
        }         

        // RENDERER
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );
        renderer.gammaInput = true;
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        // Orbit Controls

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
        controls.enableDamping = true;
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
        controls.enableZoom = true;

        //
        stats = new Stats();
        container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
        //

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );


        render();
        stats.update();
    }


    function render() {

        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that your lighting is correct (such as by using a primitive square)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code and model.

For the model: The entry `mapLight` should have been named `mapDiffuse`. I know you are exporting the model so you need to find how to make this happen.

For the code:

1. Your ambient light is very strong. It washes out everything. Try a value of `0x222222` or remove it from the scene totally.
2. Your `camera` does not need to be added to the scene.
3. Remove `renderer.setClearColor( fog_color )` just to see if you get the correct meshes and materials first. Then you can go the scene effects.
4. Your texture size is way big. It is not supported in webgl. Try a size of 1024 and then move up is you need to.
5. Finally your `loader.onLoadComplete()` is never called (and will never be). Move that part of the code in your `loader.load()` callback function.

After all this you will see your girl.

Comment: mapdiffuse nailed it. I was using example for the code, i can optimise now thank you very much!